# Toggle with callback scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form that I toggle to show/hide. I want the screen to scroll to the toggled content when it's visible. The button that triggers the toggle is located at the bottom of the screen and the toggled area appears bellow the button.

```
$(document).on('click', "#MyButton", function () {
    $("#MyToggle").slideToggle("slow", callback);

});

function callback() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#MyToggle").offset().top
    }, 2000);
};
```

The toggle works perfectly, but the scroll seem to start working when I toggle the second time. If I hide and show the toggle again the page scrolls down as it should. What am I missing?

Comment: You can post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), increase your chances of getting a better answer.

Comment: That is unclear.... But what I see is the page will scroll to the very top when `MyToggle` is hidden, because its `offset.top` is zero. Maybe that's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. The reason this didn't work is because there was a 100% height set to the body element. I know this was close to impossible to figure out from the info I provided. I'll leave the answer here if anyone else ever has the same problem.